# join table in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 table in laravel:

```
class General extends Mode
{
 public function populars()
    {
        return this->hasMany('App\Popular');
    }
}

enter code here
```

and

```
class Popular extends Model
{
    public function general()
    {
        return  this->belongsTo('App\General');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Specific extends Model
{
public function popular(){
        return this->belongsTo('App\Popular');
    }
}
...
```

how to join tables and return this list result:

```
 1. generals
     2.popular
      3.Specific
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume `Popular` has many `Specific`, you could add another mapping in `Popular` model as

```
class Popular extends Model
{
    public function general()
    {
        return  this->belongsTo('App\General');
    }
    public function specific()
    {
        return this->hasMany('App\Specific');
    }

}
```

Doing with eloquent way you could write it as

```
$generals = General::with('populars.specific')->get();
```

Using query builder you could join them as

```
DB::table('general as g')
    ->join('popular as p', 'g.id','=','p.general_id')
    ->join('specific as s', 'p.id','=','p.popular_id')
    ->get();
```